# Save a Custom Deck

Tags: the-secret-world

I've been playing the secret world in a casual manner for quite a while but I never thought to explore the ["Decks"](http://www.thesecretworld.com/world/decks) feature until the previous weekend, up until that point I simply chose whichever actives and passives I thought looked interesting or useful; the result of which is illustrated in the following screenshot.

[image: My Deck]

I have two other characters and I have managed to try out two of the starter decks on those, and by coincidence my first (I suppose main) character happens to have the abilities required for the "Polariser" starter deck.

In the screenshot there is a button in the bottom left labeled "Equip Deck" this button will take all the active and passive abilities for that deck and assign them to my character. I haven't pressed it for this character as yet, because I first want to find out if there is a way to save my ability choices so that I can re assign them later.

So my question is, how can I save a custom deck?

**Equipped Actives**
Ignition
Forking Paths
Balanced Blade
Fire Manifestation
Thor's Hammer
Surging Blades
Molten Earth

**Equipped Passives**
Elemental Force
Delicate Precision
Hothead
Expose Weakness
Toxic Earth
Sharp Blades
Enervate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press C to bring up your Character Sheet, and select Gear Management - you can use this to save Decks, including currently equipped Talismans and Weapons. You start with 5 slots, and can buy additional slots from your Faction HQ.

You can also install add-ons that do a similar function - [Viper's Deck Manager](http://www.curse.com/tsw-mods/tsw/deck-manager) is the one I use.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't realise that "Gear Management" could be used for that. I used the dressing room feature before, but never thought to pay much attention to the gear management option, I guess it's since I'd never reached the point of needing to manage gear. I tried out the addin you mentioned but I was getting choppy framerates (not sure if that had anything to do with the addon or just time of day) so I removed it, for the time being the gear management feature is just what I need